# Adjust height for only one bar of my plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this dataframe

```
data = {'reference':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'Total'],
        'label_1':[58.3,75.0,88.0,81.1,60.0,72.0,50.0,85.7,73.8],
       'label_2':[41.7, 25.0, 9.3,17.0,40.0,27.3,40.9,14.3,24.5],
       'label_3':[0.0,0.0,4.7,1.9,0.0,0.8,9.1,0.0,1.7]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('reference')
data
```

I have made an horizontal barplot who look like this

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data.plot(kind='barh',  stacked=True,  width=0.70,  ax=ax,  figsize= (15, 15))
ax.legend(["label_1",
           "label_2",
          "label_3"], loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1));
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
fmt = '%.0f%%'
xticks = mtick.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xticks)

for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center', fmt='%.0f%%')

ax.set_yticklabels( ('name_1', 'name_2','name_3', 'name_4', 'name_5', 'name_6', 'name_7', 'name_8', 'TOTAL') )
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to space up the 'Total' bar, I don't have any idea how to adjust the height for only one specific bar on my plot. Any help is appreciated, thx everyone!

Comment: Do you mean the *thickness* of the bar when you say "height"? Because for me, height still signifies the actual value of the bar (which should always be 100%; well, except for name_3 apparently).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, I mean, the distance, I want the 'Total' bar to be offset upwards from the others

Comment: So not the height of thickness, but the width to the next bar. It's y-position should be higher up?

Comment: can you give more details on what you would like to move? Maybe annotate the current graph?

Comment: "It's y-position should be higher up?" Yeah that's it !

Comment: I can now change the height, but I will need to add margins as well. `ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center', fmt='%.0f%%');c[8].set_height(1.0)`

Comment: Another idea would be drawing a greyed background behind the "total" bar: `ax.axhspan(len(data)-1.5, len(data)-0.5, color='lightgrey', zorder=0)` or jjust draw a separator line `ax.axhline(len(data)-1.5, lw=0.8, color='black')`